# Distributivity of $\times$ over $+$

Tags: abstract-algebra, binary-operations

I had a problem recently as part of class work that dealt with sets and the conditions imposed by them. This is part of a larger question that I simplified things down to. The parts I'm concerned with are

> 1. Is $+$ associative?
> 2. Is $\times$ distributive with respect to $+$?

I've tried several combinations and can't find anything that shows it's not true. However, some of my classmates argue that there is in fact a combination that shows it is not true.

Here are the addition and multiplication tables I ended up with. Is there any combination that can act as a counterexample? (I guess off the bat, you can eliminate combinations involving $0$s):

$$
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
+ & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 2 \\
2 & 2 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
3 & 3 & 2 & 1 & 0
\end{array} \qquad
\begin{array}{c|cccc}
\times & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
2 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 0 \\
3 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 3
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$1+(1+3)=1+2=3,\quad\text{but}\quad(1+1)+3=2+3=1$$

$$1+(2+3)=1+1=2,\quad\text{but}\quad(1+2)+3=3+3=0$$

There are probably others.

$$2(1+2)=2(3)=0,\quad\text{but}\quad2(1)+2(2)=2+2=2$$

Again, there are probably others.